# Pass Select command as parameter and execute in temp table

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server-2008

I want to pass a `SELECT` query as parameter to `STORED PROCEDURE` in SQL Server 2008.
In that sp execute that query and store to temp table and then I want to loop a cursor on the 2 field of that temp table.

So how can I do that??
Mainly this part : **`execute that query and store to temp table`**

Edit :

Query :

```
SELECT * FROM SomeView WHERE COL1 = '1' AND COL = GETDATE() ORDER BY COL0
```

There are many fields in SomeView but I want only 2 : COLS1, CLOS2
I want to loop CURSOR on that 2 fields only

Comment: Please read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html), it will answer all your questions about dynamic sql. And I think you'll need a global temp table (`##`)

Comment: ok........... where is your query and stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can store query result from a dynamic SQL query to a temp table:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @sql = 'SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM SomeView WHERE COL1 = ''1'' AND COL = GETDATE() ORDER BY COL0'

CREATE TABLE #temp(col1 <yourDataType>, col2 <yourDataType>)
INSERT INTO #temp EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

But you should really consider alternative to cursor, cursors degrade performance, cursors operate row by row whereas queries do set based operations. SQL Server is optimized for set based data access. If you can write a query don't use cursor.

Comment: Thanks a lot... but I have to check each row first and than update that row... COL1 & COL2 are just ids... Suggestions are appreciated..

Comment: Good news : I have removed cursor with the help of temp table ... Thanks

Comment: @Sac Great, you're welcome, I had a feeling that cursor was not really that needed :)